# Website got redirecting

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, malware, malware-detection

My website is getting redirected to some other URls that contain different Ads.
It is a Wordpress website. The Website is scanned using securi Scanner and said

- Domain blacklisted by Norton Safe Web
- Domain blacklisted By Yandex (via Sophos)

  Siteguard wb site shows some website malware in javascript
- http://www.renaatus.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3
- http://www.renaatus.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1

The website is affected with malware Help me out to remove the malware

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is too broad. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make your question specific.

Comment: Added few more things now can you answer

Comment: Problem is not with your domain, problem is your site has been injected with malwares. There are many articles on this.. one link https://www.optimizesmart.com/malware-removal-checklist-for-wordpress-diy-security-guide/ and there should not be any problem with java script files that you have mentioned if they are original file(Not updated) and if updated then put new jquery files

Comment: Thanks for your information let me try with that and let u know @  webDev

Comment: With javascript it is redirecting, Without Javascrip it is not so it may have proplem with javascript ? help me

Answer (score 0):

Search for infected files using below bash command:

```
grep -r ";document\[_" /path/to/www/folder/
```

And if you want to list only file names then add -l

```
grep -rl ";document\[_" /path/to/www/folder/
```

and change all folder permission to 755 using below command:

```
find /path/to/www/folder/* -type d ! -perm 0755 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
```

note: command will change directory permission to 755 if not.

Replace infected file with your backup files.